# How to specify local folder SVN path for Teamcity

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, teamcity

I just installed teamcity on my local win7 machine for testing CI for a Visual studio, VB.Net project. I can't figure out how to specify the local folder for SVN URL connection , screenshot below. My svn repository is in c:\test folder by the way.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image: Snapshot of Teamcity]

Answer (score 0):

Url of svn repository "file:///C:/test folder".
i think you can give any VCS root name you want.

Comment: actually this gives me an error 'Expected format 1 to 5, found 6' :(

Comment: I have just checked, it looks like teamcity 8.1 is the only one which supports file:/// .... trying it now

Answer (score 0):

The root name is just the name of the VCS Root, if you let it blank, TC will name it.

You have to specify the URL of where your SVN is on the web and the Username and Password if it has it.

Comment: thanks but actually now ,after reading teamcity documentation i have confirmeed that when using svn 1.8.3 , teamcity 8.1 preview version must be used for file:///